# Help to animate children div JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying something like this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('nav ul li').hover(
        function() {
            $('this.menu1bar').animate({ backgroundColor: "#95c938" }, "fast");
            $('this.menu2bar').animate({ backgroundColor: "#95c938" }, "fast");
        },
        function() {
            $('this.menu1bar').animate({ backgroundColor: "#a99672" }, "fast");
            $('this.menu2bar').animate({ backgroundColor: "#a99672" }, "fast");
       }
   );
   });
```

The objective of this code is animate the children div .menu1bar and .menu2bar can anyone help with this step, the code works for all children divs of UL, but im only want the children of LI hover event.

Comment: Is that your actual code? `$('this.menu1bar')` shouldn't select any elements, because there is no `<this>` HTML element.

Comment: @Matt: I just sat looking at this for two minutes thinking 'surely that doesn't work' but then I was confused by the "the code works for all children divs of UL" statement. Thanks for easing my troubled mind... =) +1

Comment: @David: yeah, the question wording hurts my head.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#nav ul li').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).find('.menu1bar,.menu2bar').animate({ backgroundColor: "#95c938" }, "fast");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).find('.menu1bar,.menu2bar').animate({ backgroundColor: "#a99672" }, "fast");
       }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to select a specific element. Something like this:

```
$('this').children('.menu1bar').animate({ backgroundColor: "#95c938" }, "fast");
```

**Edit:**

Of course you can also use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/), but there's a difference:

- Find() searches all children, all
  levels, also grandchildren.
- Children() searches only first level
  children.

Comment: So in children() should be faster?

Comment: @Emmanuel I think so, never tested it... It also depends on what you want. If you want to match all levels children you have to use find(), otherwise children() is good enough. By the way, this is a nice subject for some testing, i'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Please show your HTML Markup. I think that the problem might be in the following...

```
$('this.menu1bar')
```

try

```
$(this).find('.menu1bar')
```